# Mui Switch track color is not working when checked

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want different colors of track on checked and unchecked. On unchecked the track color is working but on checked the background color is default:

Checked:

[image: Checked]

Unchecked:

[image: Unchecked]

```
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';

<Switch
  sx={{
    ".MuiSwitch-thumb": {
      backgroundColor: "#FF9528"
    },
    ".MuiSwitch-track": {
      backgroundColor: "#FF4823"
    },
    "& .Mui-checked": {
      ".MuiSwitch-thumb": {
        backgroundColor: "#FF4823"
      },
      ".MuiSwitch-track": {
        backgroundColor: "#FF4823"
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.

In the example provided by MUI documentation at the Customize section, for some reason, the checked version of the track needs to have CSS selector of `+` so the name should be`+.MuiSwitch-track` instead of just `.MuiSwitch-track`.

#### UPDATED

So the default path is overwriting the `checked` version of the styling, therefore we need to extend the CSS selector a bit so the custom styling will have slight higher priority than the default one. Below is how I get it fixed inspired from the official doc.

```
  <Switch
    sx={{
      ".MuiSwitch-thumb": {
        backgroundColor: "#FF9528"
      },
      ".MuiSwitch-track": {
        backgroundColor: "#FF4823"
      },
      "& .MuiSwitch-switchBase": {
        "&.Mui-checked": {
          "+ .MuiSwitch-track": {
            backgroundColor: "#FF4823"
          },
          ".MuiSwitch-thumb": {
            backgroundColor: "#FF4823"
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  />
```

Link to the example code in MUI doc -- https://mui.com/material-ui/react-switch/#customization

Here is a demo in CodeSandbox with your code https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-jasper-5vqjgn?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: bro still same Have you tried this ?? I was trying diff methods but after refreshing the page the track color on checked is still default blue

Comment: Its working but when I refresh the page the track color on checked is back to blue.

Comment: Ooof its being overwritten by the default CSS rules because the default one has much longer path. Let me work on it for a bit and brb.

Comment: ok bro thank you for help

Comment: Alright I really do believe that this time it will work now, even after reloading. Thanks for being patient! Give it a look and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes bro its working thank you so much. but why this MUI styling is so complex ?

Comment: @UsamaMaqsood I do not know the good answer to that, but you are absolutely not wrong there lol

Comment: @UsamaMaqsood did that work for you? If it did, an upvote or accepting this answer make my day. Thanks :)

Comment: I already upvoted but I dont have enough reputations yet thats why the votes are not increasing. Accept answer option is also not showing to me I have to increase my reputations first which I started from today.